# What contents "errorMessage()" function in Angular testing docs. (see the description)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-test

I'm unable to find any source or explanations about `errorMessage()` function which written here:

https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync.

Can you help me to sort out, what it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code for `errorMessage()` function is:**

```
// Helper function to get the error message element value
// An *ngIf keeps it out of the DOM until there is an error
const errorMessage = () => {
  const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.error');
  return el ? el.textContent : null;
};
```

To find this code:

**1-** Download example for testing code from here:

https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync

So, in the top of the page click on download example

Direct link: https://angular.io/generated/zips/testing/testing.zip

**2-** unzip the file testing.zip and go to this directory: `\testing\src\app\twain`

**3-** Open the file `twain.component.spec`

So you will find the helper function `errorMessage()` in the top of the file and even the test that the link you given in the question refers to.